# AAPT out(634534754) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done

Tags: java, android, xml, image, android-drawable

While creating a project I saw these errors, I was putting images in drawable folder and then I was compiling my project then these problem occure.

I'm getting these error message again and again:-

```
   :app:mergeDebugResources
    AAPT out(634534754) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
    AAPT out(157551984) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
    AAPT out(1054964944) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
    AAPT out(942612022) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
    AAPT out(1202935217) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
    AAPT out(804862562) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
    AAPT err(634534754): libpng error: Not a PNG file
    AAPT err(804862562): libpng error: Not a PNG file
    AAPT err(1829516134): D:\firstapp\app\src\main\res\drawable-ldpi\gesture.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT err(1054964944): libpng error: Not a PNG file
    AAPT err(942612022): D:\firstapp\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\frame.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT err(942612022): libpng error: Not a PNG file
    AAPT err(1202935217): libpng error: Not a PNG file
    AAPT err(211209819): D:\firstapp\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\title_bar_menu_on.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
    AAPT err(157551984): libpng error: Not a PNG file
    AAPT err(157551984): D:\LoginDemo\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\title_bar_menu.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
```

Why it is happening? It is only going in these projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens by some of reasons ,
1>when you move a project of eclipse to android stdio .
2>when your image files are broken 
How to solve error ?
For solving these issue 
1>you must open image files in any editor and then try to save image file .
2>you must reload project when you fix all infected files by previous step .
I hope it will solve error .